# App申請時に4sサイズ用スクリーンショットが無いためにエラーとなる

Tags: ios, xcode, iphone, apple

iTunes ConnectでAppを申請するときに4s用（3.5inch）スクリーンショットは必須なのでしょうか。

※ アプリ自体は、4s、5/5s/5c、6、6 Plus、iPadに対応しています。4sには対応していません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

> iTunes ConnectでAppを申請するときに4s用（3.5inch）スクリーンショットは必須なのでしょうか。

必須です。質問の画像に書いてあるメッセージ通りです。

> ※ アプリ自体は、4s、5/5s/5c、6、6 Plus、iPadに対応しています。4sには対応していません。

iPhone4sに対応しているんですか? 対応していないんですか?
いずれにしてもAppStoreでiPhone用のアプリをリリースするにはiPhone4sの対応は必須です。
ユーザーが少なくなったとはいえ、OSがサポートしている古いデバイスの対応を
アプリが勝手に打ち切るなということだと思います。